# Monkey Patch 'at_with_coercion' (activesupport) / Handle milliseconds from epoch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport

#### Description

We have a Ruby and Rails application with a web frontend and an API to support web calls from outside the frontend. We use the API in one use case to create and update work orders (resource) from calling an web url and sending the parameters as raw JSON data to our API controller (separate controller with separate route).
One attribute of an work order is 'due_date' which is defined in the model as a field of type DateTime (through Mongoid).
While Rails tries to instantiate the new object of a work order in the controller with the given parameters the transformation into the defined database fieldtypes gets done. For DateTime fields this is done internally by calling “at_with_coercion” in rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb in line  44 (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.6/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L44).
Because the API is called from outside there is an use case to set the 'due_date' field with an integer number which contains the amount of milliseconds from epoch time (1970-01-01 01:00:00).
Rails can only handle an integer which contains the amount of seconds from epoch time.
So we tried to monkey patch the internal “at_with_coercion” method but ran into some issues.

#### Steps to reproduce

Model:

```rb
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
field :due_date, type: DateTime
```

Controller:

```rb
def create
  @work_order = WorkOrder.new(params.require(:work_order).permit(:name, … , :due_date, … ))
  @work_order.save
end
```

Monkey Patches
lib/core_extensions/time.rb:

```rb
class Time
  class << self
    remove_method :at_without_coercion
    remove_method :at_with_coercion
    remove_method :at

    # Layers additional behavior on Time.at so that ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone and DateTime
    # instances can be used when called with a single argument
    def at_with_coercion(*args)
      return at_without_coercion(*args) if args.size != 1

      # Time.at can be called with a time or numerical value
      time_or_number = args.first

      if time_or_number.is_a?(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone) || time_or_number.is_a?(DateTime)
        at_without_coercion(time_or_number.to_f).getlocal
      elsif time_or_number.is_a?(Integer) && time_or_number.to_s.length == 13
        time_or_number /= 1000.0
        at_without_coercion(time_or_number)
      else
        at_without_coercion(time_or_number)
      end
    end
    alias at_without_coercion at
    alias at at_with_coercion
  end
end
```

config/initializers/monkey_patches.rb:

```rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'core_extensions', '*.rb')].sort.each do |f|
  require f
end
```

API call:
URL: {{protocol}}://{{subdomain}}.{{url}}/api/v2/work_orders.json
Parameters (raw JSON): {

```json
"work_order":{
    "name":"Test workorder",
    ... ,
    "due_date":1669105754783,
    ...
    }
}
```

#### Expected behavior

Rails should use our monkey patched method and return the correct formatted Time value.

#### Actual behavior

If we don’t remove the existing aliases the calls to “at_without_coercion” leads to the internal Rails method alias and we get a StackLevel too deep exception.
If we override the aliases we end up in an infinity loop following a StackLevel to deep exception because the overriden method calls itself multiple times.

#### System configuration

**Rails version**: 5.2.6

**Ruby version**: 2.5.9p229

**Mongoid gem version**: 7.3.1

#### Alternatives

If there is no possibility to monkey patch the internal method is there a possibility so Rails can handle an amount of milliseconds from epoch time?

Comment: Honestly it is not clear why did you decide monkey-patching instead of _explicit_ normalizing of the input itself.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov We have multiple resources (so multiple controllers) with DateTime fields and we also don't want to update the normalizing every time a DateTime field get's added to a resource. So we thought the best solution would be to do it on a central component so it will cover all resources and use cases.

Comment: You could use middleware, you could introduce a simple DSL so that this normalization could be added to a particular controller in a single **yet explicit** line etc etc etc. To me, in terms of long-term app maintainability, the idea of "monkey-patching monkey-patched" sounds indistinguishable from "targeting your own leg with the loaded gun".

Comment: P.S. If you still decide to proceed with monkey-patching, please note that your initializers (from `config/initializers/`) are _not guaranteed_ to be executed after the rails initialization process is completed. If you want your monkey-patch to be added on top of all Rails' ones you probably would like to do it from `after_initialize` callback...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Thank you for your replies and your suggestion of using a middleware. 
We could get the monkey patch working but decided to go with your suggestion and created a concern in which we do the checks and convertions and call this concern in a before_validation callback in the relevant models.
Please add your solution by adding a middleware as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.